# SQL - Incorrect Syntax -Using a string with slashes as a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to make this query but I get incorrect syntax and not sure why. Does the slashes need to be escaped?

```
with x as (
    select
        job_id,
        avg_runtime,
        id,
        row_number() over (partition by ja.job_id order by ja.id desc) rn
    from
        job_activity as ja 
            join 
        job as j 
            on ja.job_id = j.id 
    where
        j.name in ('/THE/Name/goes/here')
        and
        ja.avg_runtime <> 0 and
        ja.avg_runtime is not null        
) select
    job_id,
    avg_runtime,
    id
from
    x
where
    rn = 1;
```

Comment: ''/THE/Name/goes/here''

Comment: It saids Invaild column name. not sure why? ON that particular line /THE/Name/goes/here'

Comment: Show the actual string,are there numbers before/,spaces?Also I` guessing sql server?

Comment: Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: Invalid column name '/job/type/run/case_word_deal'.

Comment: I don't see a variable being used, are you saying the query is a variable, or that the string in your `IN()` is a variable?

Comment: Are you building this dynamically?Whats the sql server version?Edit your question with the whole code.

Comment: And add the complete error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should run as-is.  Are you using the slashed-string as a place-holder?  If so, you might want to try this:

```
Declare @JobToFind VarChar(30)

Set @jobtofind = 'Search string (job name)'--modify the value in the quotes.

with x as (
    select
        job_id,
        avg_runtime,
        j.ID,
        row_number() over (partition by ja.job_id order by ja.id desc) rn
    from
        job_activity as ja 
            join 
        job as j 
            on ja.job_id = j.id 
    where
        j.name =@JobToFind
        and
        ja.avg_runtime <> 0 and
        ja.avg_runtime is not null        
) select
    job_id,
    avg_runtime,
    id
from
    x
where
    rn = 1;
```